# Value look-up for Dictionary inside a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary in this format :

```
mongo = {
    1: {'syno': ['a','b','c'], 'can': ['2','3','4']},
    2 :{'syno': ['x','y','z'], 'can': ['6','7','8']},
}
```

and I have a list called `syno_iter`:

```
syno_iter = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Using a single value in `syno_iter`, let's suppose `a`. I want to get the values in the `can` in the `mongo{}` as in if the value `a` is available in the value of the value `syno`, we can return `can`.

We don't have any way of knowing the keys of mongo dict. Also as dictionaries are not iterable we can't use range thing.

To reiterate:

I want to do something like this-

```
for i in syno_iter:
    if i in (mongo.values('syno')):
        print mongo.values('can'(values()))
```

> ```
> input - 'a'
> output - ['2','3','4']
> ```

Comment: Not clear what you are saying, Can you please edit your question with desired output ?

Comment: "Also as dictionaries are not iterable" not sure were you got this from. You can always iterate a dictionary `for key in mongo` or `for key, value in mongo.iteritems()`

Comment: @RahulKP done with the output

Comment: @FlyingTeller will try this right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a lookup like that with:

#### Code:

```
def get_syno_values(data, lookup):
    for row in data.values():
        if lookup in row['syno']:
            return row['can']
```

#### Test Code:

```
mongo = {
    1: {'syno': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'can': ['2', '3', '4']},
    2: {'syno': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'can': ['6', '7', '8']}
}
syno_iter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print(get_syno_values(mongo, 'a'))
print(get_syno_values(mongo, 'y'))
```

#### Results:

```
['2', '3', '4']
['6', '7', '8']
```